# Getting error with the message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web

Getting below error while calling Web API through console application using HTTP client.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

In Background Service does work but application get a crash with this message.

I tried lots of solutions but none has worked out.

The code:

```
 string infolder_ = inFolder.Trim();

            string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InvokeFlexServiceURL"];
            URL = ReplaceEndPoint(URL);
            Console.WriteLine(URL);

            string urlParameters = "?infolder=" + infolder_ + "&jobId=" + JobId + "&client=" + client_ + "";
            Console.WriteLine(urlParameters);
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(urlParameters,null).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(messge.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(messge.ReasonPhrase);
            string description = string.Empty;
            if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                description = result;
                Console.WriteLine(messge.StatusCode);

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: i have posted my code , please check

Comment: Posted where? There's no code in the question yet

Comment: Is the url http or https?

Comment: it is there now.

Comment: Hi, it is http  we are using

Comment: What is the value of `urlParameters` when it fails?

Comment: ?infolder=Somenetworklocation&jobId=1733&client=XYZ

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be because of the proxy issue. Please try bypassing proxy with below line of code,

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Please remove this line from your production code. This is just for testing

Comment: Hi, It didn't work for me, i have posted my code below

Comment: ok . I have noticed that you have posted your code in the answer section. Please move it to the part of question